Gradients of the Lagrangian flow map, applying Gronwall's inequality
I'm new to here, so please understand some mistakes I make.
In text 'The mathematical Analysis of the Incompressible Euler and Navier-Stokes Equations' by Vicol and Bedrossian, in page 3, the author calculated the equation
\begin{align}
\partial_t\frac{\partial X_j}{\partial a_k}(t,a)=\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}(t,X(t,a))\frac{\partial X_i}{\partial a_k}(t,a), \quad \frac{\partial X_j}{\partial a_k}(a,0)=\delta_{jk} \tag{1}
\end{align}
from the relation of Eulerian and Lagrangian
\begin{align}
\partial_t X(t,a)=u(t,X(t,a))
\end{align}
where $X$ is the Lagrangian flow map. I successfully computed this derivation by chain rule. But next, they suggested an inequality
\begin{align}
\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}^d}|\nabla_aX(t,a)|\leq\exp\bigg(\int_0^t\lVert\nabla u(s) \rVert_{L^\infty}ds\bigg)
\end{align}
by applying the Gronwall's inequailty to (1).
I lost my way at this point, so can you give me any hint of it?
Thank you.
